# How to make a class copy itself into another class with a different name that can be executed with Java?

Tags: java

What I would like to do is to **copy** the compiled class [lets call it **ClassA.class**] given its file-name (within the code as a String), into a new file (also defined as a String within ClassA) [lets call it **ClassB.class**], **and to be able to execute** that new copied class (with a new file name) using "**javac ClassB**".

What would be the best and the most concise way to do this ?

EDIT: SOLUTION THAT WORKED....

Hex-Editing the file from ClassA to ClassB worked !
So I guess anything that would change the binary code would work, having the filenames of the constant (same) length.

Comment: `public class ClassB extends ClassA`?

Comment: Wait.  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Do you want to provide java source code as string, and compile it at runtime? Kind of a hack?

Comment: @Rogue Sorry, but not what I wanted to ask. ClassB is a randomly generated String. I need to copy the file ClassA.class as ClassB.class and be able to run it with [java ClassB]. Copying is done with ClassA's code.

Comment: For what do you need that?

Comment: @AlexWien a quick A.L. experiment with an option for the  self-replication and mutation. Maybe Java is a wrong language then ?

Comment: You can't copy the source code of a compiled class without decompiling

Comment: I don't think Java's the right language for that.  You're trying to change file names on the fly, which Java uses for a specific purpose.

Comment: @Santiago, I was afraid of that, unless there is a hex-edit-like method to replace the class-name within the *.class itself... but then that would just make things more and more complicated instead of short and simple.  THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy a class with byte-code manipulation libraries (Javassist, Asm, BCEL).

With Javassist it would be along the lines of (haven't tried):

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass cc = pool.get("ClassA");
cc.setName("ClassB");
cc.writeFile("ClassB.class");
```